# How to convert List<IEntity> to List<Entity>?

Tags: c#

How to convert List to List?

IEntity is my interface and Entity is a class that implements IEntity.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<IEntity> myList;
//initialization omitted

List<Entity> convertedList = myList.OfType<Entity>().ToList();
```

Of course, this will yield ONLY those items that are of type `Entity`.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;
List<Entity> newList = list.Cast<Entity>().ToList();
//or
List<Entity> newList = list.OfType<Entity>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not for the general case - Not all `ientity` are necessarily `entity` (i.e. could be another class implementing the same interface) - the other way round it would be possible with a `Cast()` operation on the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to do it.  The [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method will extract out the entities that are your specific class, which you can use to build the list:

```
 List<IEntity> theEntities = GetEntities();
 List<YourEntity> newList = theEntities.OfType<YourEntity>().ToList();
```

If you know, for sure, that all of your entities are your specific class, then you can use [`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
 List<IEntity> theEntities = GetEntities();
 List<YourEntity> newList = theEntities.Cast<YourEntity>().ToList();
```